# Extracting overlapping polygons using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I'm trying to extract polygons on one layer that overlap with polygons on another layer using ArcGIS Pro. I've followed [this approach](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/215683/136934) by accessing Related Data.

[image]

Indeed, I can view the overlapping polygons, but is there a way to extract these overlapping polygons onto a separate layer?

Can polygons be extracted using the `OBJECTID` in each related data row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all the overlapped polygons and right click at the layer, select Data -> Export Data and activate the option "Only selected features".